# What does J1, J2 and J3 represent on a Schematic?

Tags: schematics

I'm looking at this schematic for the TSL1401 line scan camera module and trying to understand what the various pins do. I understand what the labels SI, CLK, AO and Vdd mean but I'm totally lost when it comes to what the J1, J2 & J3 mean.

Here is a picture with the J labeled:

[image]

Can anyone here shine some light on this? I looked it up online and it seemed like it was a pretty standared term but I can't find any good documentation on it.

Answer (score 6):

J1, J2 and J3 are reference designators for connectors (or in some cases specifically pin headers).

Answer (score 2):

The "J" stands for "jumper", although the designator is also used for off-board connectors as well as jumper pins.

Comment: I use "J" for "jack" as well as for Jumper.

Comment: I actually see "J" used for "jack" more frequently than I see it used for "jumper".